# Connect to REST service in Android through Multipart request with JSON

Tags: android, rest, multipart, image-upload

I m trying to connect to a REST service which takes a json object and an image and returns the text from the image (after OCR).

The [documentation](http://docs.openocr.apiary.io/#reference/openocr/ocr-decode-via-url/ocr-decode) of the REST service states that the request must me similar to :

```
-----BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/json

{"engine":"tesseract"}
-----BOUNDARY

-----BOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: attachment;
Content-Type: image/png
filename="attachment.txt".

PNGDATA.........
-----BOUNDARY
```

So I referred to [this tutorial](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/upload-files-by-sending-multipart-request-programmatically) and modified the code, when I run the code it gives me following error:

```
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection{192.168.0.102:8080, proxy=DIRECT@ hostAddress=192.168.0.102 cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1} (recycle count=0)
```

Following are contents of my **MultipartUtility.java** file

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * For sending Multipart requests: modified for OCR
 *http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/upload-files-by-sending-multipart-request-programmatically
 *
 */
public class MultipartUtility {
    private final String boundary;
    private static final String LINE_FEED = "\r\n";
    private HttpURLConnection httpConn;
    private String charset;
    private OutputStream outputStream;
    private PrintWriter writer;

    /**
     * This constructor initializes a new HTTP POST request with content type
     * is set to multipart/form-data
     * @param requestURL
     * @param charset
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public MultipartUtility(String requestURL, String charset)
            throws IOException {
        this.charset = charset;


        boundary = "---BOUNDARY";

        URL url = new URL(requestURL);
        httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
        httpConn.setDoOutput(true); // indicates POST method
        httpConn.setDoInput(true);
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "multipart/related; boundary=" + boundary);
 //       httpConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "CodeJava Agent");
   //     httpConn.setRequestProperty("Test", "Bonjour");
        outputStream = httpConn.getOutputStream();
        writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, charset),
                true);
    }

    /**
     * Adds a form field to the request
     *
     */
    public void addFormField() {
        writer.append(boundary).append(LINE_FEED);
      //  writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + name + "\"")
        //        .append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append("Content-Type: application/json").append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append("{\"engine\":\"tesseract\"}").append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(boundary).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();
    }

    /**
     * Adds a upload file section to the request
     * @param fieldName name attribute in <input type="file" name="..." />
     * @param uploadFile a File to be uploaded
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void addFilePart(String fieldName, File uploadFile)
            throws IOException {
        String fileName = uploadFile.getName();
        writer.append(boundary).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append("Content-Disposition: attachment;")
                .append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append("Content-Type: image/png").append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append("filename="+fileName+".").append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(LINE_FEED);


    //adding png data here
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = -1;
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        inputStream.close();

        writer.append(boundary).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();
    }

    /**
     * Adds a header field to the request.
     * @param name - name of the header field
     * @param value - value of the header field
     */
    public void addHeaderField(String name, String value) {
        writer.append(name + ": " + value).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();
    }

    /**
     * Completes the request and receives response from the server.
     * @return a list of Strings as response in case the server returned
     * status OK, otherwise an exception is thrown.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public List<String> finish() throws IOException {
        List<String> response = new ArrayList<>();

      //  writer.append(LINE_FEED).flush();
     //   writer.append("--" + boundary + "--").append(LINE_FEED);

        writer.close();

        // checks server's status code first
        int status = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    httpConn.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                response.add(line);
            }
            reader.close();
            httpConn.disconnect();
        } else {
            throw new IOException("Server returned non-OK status: " + status);
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

I'm using this MultipartUtility in my **MainActivty.java** file:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //OkHttpClient client;
    String serverUrl = "http://192.168.0.102:8080/ocr-file-upload";
    String imgUrl;
    String TAG = "MainAcivity";
    TextView tvMain;
    File uploadFile1;
    String charset = "UTF-8";
    Button btn_make_request;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn_make_request = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_make_request);
        tvMain = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_main);
       // client = new OkHttpClient();
        imgUrl = Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/ocr_test.png";
        uploadFile1 = new File(imgUrl);




        btn_make_request.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(isStoragePermissionGranted())
                    new UploadImage().execute();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "PERMISSION PROBLEM", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        });



    }//edn oncreate

    private class UploadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            Log.v(TAG, "IN DO IN BACKGROUND");
            //   upload(serverUrl);
             doMultipartOcr();
            //doRequest();
            return null;
        }
    }


    public void doMultipartOcr(){
        try {
            MultipartUtility multipart = new MultipartUtility(serverUrl, charset);
           // multipart.addHeaderField("Content-Type", "multipart/related");
           // multipart.addHeaderField("boundary=", "---BOUNDARY");
            multipart.addFormField();
            multipart.addFilePart("fileUpload", uploadFile1);
            List<String> response = multipart.finish();
            for (String line : response) {
                //TODO: display Output
                tvMain.setText(tvMain.getText() + "\n" + line);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            //TODO: display error
            Log.v(TAG, ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public  boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
                return true;
            } else {

                Log.v(TAG,"Permission is revoked");
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                return false;
            }
        }
        else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
            Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
            return true;
        }


    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if(grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Log.v(TAG,"Permission: "+permissions[0]+ "was "+grantResults[0]);
            //resume tasks needing this permission
        }
    }


}
```

I'm new to android development and I'm trying to figure out how to use this REST web service in my app form last 2-3 days but I'm unable to get it to work.

Also please let me know if there is any better/easier way to use [this web](http://docs.openocr.apiary.io/#reference/openocr/ocr-decode-via-url/ocr-decode) service in android app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is use loopj library for sending Http post request and use Gson library for parsing response.